# Is there a name for this type of algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, group-by

I have a 2 dimensional array forming a table:

```
[color][number][shape   ]
-------------------------
[black][10    ][square  ]
[black][10    ][circle  ]
[red  ][05    ][triangle]
[red  ][04    ][triangle]
[green][11    ][oval    ]
```

and what I want to do is group largest common denominators, such that we get:

**3 groups**

- group #1: color=black, number=10, shapes = [square, circle]
- group #2: color=red, shape=triange, numbers = [05,04]
- group #3: color=green, number=11, shape = oval

I wrote code that will handle a 2 "column" scenario, then I needed to adjusted it for 3 and I was figuring I might as well do it for n. I wanted to check first if there is some literature around this but I can't think of what to start looking for!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You're misusing "denominator", and your example doesn't illuminate much-- for example, you don't have all the triangles in one group even though "triangle" is the most common value.

Comment: oops, updating question now to change the "triangle" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Data Clustering Algorithms](http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~gk/A542/matt.pdf)** is the closest thing I could find.

And your space is 3-dimensional where each point is identified by 3-tuple `(color,number,shape)`.

1. http://home.dei.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: your references pointed me to "Correlation Clustering" which is what I wanted, thanks!

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~shuchi/papers/clusteringfull.pdf